# Does this insulation need to be replaced? Does it contain asbestos?

Tags: insulation

This is a 60y old house but I am not sure when the bathroom that is downstairs was built

this is in the ceiling and I would like to know what sort of insulation to use

[image]

the bath tub that I just removed seems to be manufactured in 92

[image]

The exterior side of the wall has the insulation shown in the third picture
[image]

Comment: Best solution: send a sample for testing.

Comment: only solution, @SolarMike...

Comment: what is it recommended to put there ? It was pretty bad chewed by mice
the guys who lived here before (at least two owners before me lived with an opening in the wall at the opposite side of the building and that was wide open highway for mice which they fought with traps and poison but never considered closing those openings.
The mice are gone now (scary experience in the first year when we moved in) but their droppings are still in the floor insulation ...found lots of it when opened the ceiling